# "Exclusive" and "Default" Subscription Modes in Rx

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, observable

I have an observable sequence of event objects and a number of observers handling specific types of events. I need to accomplish the following scenarios:

1. Some event types need to be handled by the first observer matching a condition (e.g. observable.SubscribeExclusively(x=>{}) and become "unobservable" to the others.
2. If there are no subscriptions, set some default handler (e.g. observable.SubscribeIfNoSubscriptions(x=>{})) so that no items get lost (this handler may for example save the item to a database so that it is processed later).

Is there a way to handle these cases with Rx?

Comment: I could be wrong here, but it seems like you are needing to know a little too much about your observers. In your case, I would probably create an IObservable<IObservable<X>> so that the first subscriber got Observable A and the rest got Observable B. I don't have a good suggestion for #2, which is why I've not answered.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think in the solution you suggest even an IEnumerable<IObservable<X>> would suffice. What I am interested in is however a more general problem, which is how one subscriber can stop other subscribers from receiving an event... What seems to me the most reasonable now is to have some kinds of input and output sequences which is not too far from the solution you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I *quite* grok your scenario, but how does this strike you:

```
IObservable<Event> streamOfEvents.SelectMany(x => {
    if (matchesExclusiveItem1(x)) {
        x += exclusiveItem1Handler;
        return Observable.Empty<Event>();
    }

    // Default case
    return Observable.Return(x);
}).Subscribe(x => {
    // Default case
    x += defaultHandler;
});
```

I'm using "Event objects" because that's what you specified, but it'd probably be better to use `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` - this selector has side effects (connecting the event), which is less than good.

Answer (score 1):

The "Exclusivity" is easier - you just have everybody else subscribe to the filtered output of the exclusive observer.

"Default" is harder - RX programming is a functional programming and subscribers do not know of each other, while by definition having a "Default" subscriber means  having some state **shared** between observers. One way to have shared state is to create a producer/consumer queue using [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) or BufferBlock from [TPL DataFlow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582). Another way is to attach the "processed" state to the event itself using a class like this:

```
public class Handled<T>
{
    public bool IsHandled { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

In any case, you would have to give the observers some time to react before you employ the "default" handler. The code below illustrates both "Exclusive" and "Default" concepts:

```
        var source = new[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}.ToObservable();
        var afterExclusive = source
            .Where(x =>
                       {
                           if (x == 0)
                           {
                               Console.WriteLine("exclusive");
                               return false;
                           }
                           return true;
                       })
            .Select(x => new Handled<int> {Data = x})
            .Publish(); // publish is a must otherwise 
        afterExclusive  // we'll get non shared objects
            .Do(x => { x.IsHandled = true; })
            .Subscribe();
        afterExclusive
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Where(x => !x.IsHandled)
            .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("missed by all {0}", x));
        afterExclusive.Connect();
```