# “Default” subscription if no subscriber in Rx (Reactive Extensions)

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive

I already read this question...

["Exclusive" and "Default" Subscription Modes in Rx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789237/exclusive-and-default-subscription-modes-in-rx)

My case is very similar.

I like to create something like that...

```
class Example {
    private stativ readonly Subject<Unit> EventStreamSubject =
        new Subject<Unit>();

    public static IObservable<Unit> EventStream {
        get {
            // TODO
        }
    }

    public static void SetDefault(IObserver<Unit> defaultSubscriber) {
        _defaultSubscriber = defaultSubscriber;
        // TODO
    }
    private static IObserver<Unit> _defaultSubscriber;
}
```

The rules...

- There can be only one or no DefaultSubscriber
- If there is no subscriber on the EventStream the DefaultSubscriber is used
- If any number of subscriber subscribe the EventStream the DefaultSubscriber should not recieve any element until the subscriptions are disposed
- The DefaultSubscriber could be set after the EventStream is already subscribed by another subscriber (and not used until the last subscription disposed) and vice versa

In sum... the EventStream is always subscribed if a DefaultSubscriber is available. Either by the DefaultSubscriber or by any other external subscriber (or not if there is no DefaultSubscriber).

Can I use any method in Rx to observe any changes in subscriptions?
Can I observe the subscription or observe the end of a subscription?

The difference to the other question is...
The elements have not any information about what subscriber should be used.

Thanks for any help.

Here my code I want to get run...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var defaultSubscriber = Observer.Create(x => Console.WriteLine("DefaultSubscriber is used"));
        Example.SetDefault(defaultSubscriber);

        Example.EventStreamSubject.OnNext(Unit.Default);

        using (Example.EventStream.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber 1 is used")))
        {
            Example.EventStreamSubject.OnNext(Unit.Default);

            using (Example.EventStream.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber 1.1 is used")))
            {
                Example.EventStreamSubject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
            }

            Example.EventStreamSubject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
        }

        Example.EventStreamSubject.OnNext(Unit.Default);

        using (Example.EventStream.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber 2 is used")))
        {
            using (Example.EventStream.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber 2.1 is used")))
            {
                Example.EventStreamSubject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
            }
        }

        Example.EventStreamSubject.OnNext(Unit.Default);

        // expected output:
        //      DefaultSubscriber is used
        //      Subscriber 1 is used
        //      Subscriber 1 is used
        //      Subscriber 1.1 is used
        //      Subscriber 1 is used
        //      DefaultSubscriber is used
        //      Subscriber 2 is used
        //      Subscriber 2.1 is used
        //      DefaultSubscriber is used
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution...

```
class Example
{
    internal static readonly Subject<Unit> EventStreamSubject =
        new Subject<Unit>();

    private static readonly Subject<Unit> ExternalEventStreamSubject =
        new Subject<Unit>();

    private static bool _isConnected = false;

    private static void Connect()
    {
        if (!_isConnected)
        {
            EventStreamSubject.Subscribe(ExternalEventStreamSubject);
            _isConnected = true;
        }
    }

    public static IObservable<Unit> EventStream
    {
        get
        {
            Connect();
            return ExternalEventStreamSubject.AsObservable();
        }
    }

    public static void SetDefault(IObserver<Unit> defaultSubscriber)
    {
        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(_defaultSubscriber, defaultSubscriber))
        {
            _defaultSubscription?.Dispose();

            _defaultSubscriber = defaultSubscriber;

            if (_defaultSubscriber != null)
            {
                _defaultSubscription = EventStreamSubject.
                    Where(x => !ExternalEventStreamSubject.HasObservers).
                    Subscribe(_defaultSubscriber);
            }
        }
    }
    private static IObserver<Unit> _defaultSubscriber;
    private static IDisposable _defaultSubscription;
}
```

I used another "Subject" for external subscribers.
If some external observer subscribes the EventStream, the "HasObservers"-property of the subject is true.

So I can add a default subscriber (or observer) which is used when no external subscription added.
If any external observer subscribe only the external subscribers will get the notifications (not the default observer).